# How can i change calender view code from d3 v3 to v5?

Tags: object, d3.js, calendarview

I'm having a trouble with when i want to change calendar view code (https://github.com/mohans-ca/d3js-heatmap) in d3 from v3 to v5.

I changed some parts in code like d3.timeFormat, d3.scaleLinear but there are also some missing points.

In version3 the code which i could not change to v5 code shows below:

```
 var data = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.Date; })
  .rollup(function(d) { return  Math.sqrt(d[0].Comparison_Type / Comparison_Type_Max); })
  .entries(calenderData);

console.log(data);
```

It seems on my console like below:
[image: V5 Console image]

But in V3 it should be seems like object, v3 code is below:

```
 var data = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.Date; })
  .rollup(function(d) { return  Math.sqrt(d[0].Comparison_Type / Comparison_Type_Max); })
  .map(calenderData);
```

and it seems and working in v3:
[image: V3 Console Image]

How can i change my v3 code to getting data with object?

Comment: Is there any especial reason to use V5 instead of V6?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I will use calender view visualization on my other V5 js code. But it is possible to use V6 instead of v3.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your data with this simple routine:

```
const objData = data.reduce((obj, {key, value}) => ({...obj, [key]: value}), {});
```

Comment: Hi, i tried your code and got an error, you can see below my editing code as you said, where should i change? Thank you

Comment: See my comment on your answer. Also, please note that the usual StackOverflow practice is to reply to answers with comments, not to post other answers - It's confusing. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi, thank you for advice :) i edited my code but now Object seems undefined on my console.    var objData=calenderData.reduce((obj,{key,value})=>({...obj,[key]:value}),{});

Comment: What do you see in your console?

Comment: 'Object
undefined: undefined
__proto__: Object'    i only see this undefined object. By the way, i dont know how can i insert an image on comment line so paste it console output.

Comment: Well, I think we have a mess here... Let's go back to the beginning. You say `var data = d3.nest(...` returns an array of 87 `{key, value}` objects (the first screenshot). Then, you need to convert that array to an object like in the second screenshot. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, i have calenderData which is array of 87 {key,value} which are Date and Comparison_Type (i mean values for every Date)  for my calender view. In version3, calenderData works good with d3.nest.rollup.map. With this function my calenderData looks an Object of 87. But when i change this code with version5, d3.nest.rollup.map. doesnt work, i need to show my calenderData with same in v3 like Object format.

Comment: So my answer does exactly what you need: convert an __array__ `data` to an __object__ `objData`.  Or we just don't understand each other and you need the opposite: convert an __object__ to an __array__... Please check everything again very carefully, print out your data at every step and try to figure out what's going on

Comment: Hi, i posted some codes to my answer section. You can find my reply here. Thanks

Comment: Hi, i solve my problem now thanks for your support

Comment: Glad to help :) Please mark my answer as correct.